# Item/Items property of MobileServiceCollection<TTable,TCollection> not usable

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, win-universal-app

I've found an issue that I can't figure out is why I can't access the Item property of my MobileServiceCollection once it's been instantiated and populated. Intellisense doesn't even register as it being a property of the class

Class in question: 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceCollection"

Instantiation

```
    private MobileServiceCollection<UserOnSite, UserOnSite> items;
```

Population

```
    items = await userSiteTable.ToCollectionAsync();
```

Problem

```
    items.Item(id)
```

The Item property is not listed as an Intellisense option, and gives you the following error when I attempt to use it

> 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceCollectionite.Windows.UserOnSite,PrelimOnSiteOffSite.Windows.UserOnSite>' does not >contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a >first argument of type >'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceCollectionite.Windows.UserOnSite,PrelimOnSiteOffSite.Windows.UserOnSite>' could be found >(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

According to this MSDN page Item is definitely a property and my usage is in line with previous lookups on arrays/lists etc.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn250636.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Collection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable    
    protected IList<T> Items { get; }
```

`Items` is a protected member in Collection Class which MobileServiceCollection inherit from. You can't access it via instance of MobileServiceCollection, you can only access within the MobileServiceCollection class.